# In superuser app what does force user do and what are there meanings

Tags: superuser

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy tab Pro 10.1

I have rooted my device and I have general knowledge  but I am not an expert on tablet settings and controls so I would like to ask the following question's.

In the Superuser Pro App, what is "Force user" and the following actions mean.-  :  Nobody, Net_BT, Net_Raw, Net_BT_Admin, Inet, Root, Radio, cache, shell, Media, Install, ADB, Compass, Graphics, Camera, Mount.

What are they used for, or does it depend on what app the superuser is granting access to? Some of the abbreviations I know, like Install means Install an app, or Camera means use camera, but the rest I don't know there meaning and what they do,or when they should be enabled in " Force User "

Could anyone please explain what the meanings are and when you should use these actions in "Force user"?

Answer (score 0):

**Net_BT**, **Inet** and so forth, are special users called **AIDs** (**Android IDs**). Those users are each in charge of a particular component of your device. The **Force user** option, when coupled with one of the abovementioned AIDs, lets an app act as one of those, granting it full power over the AID's specific domain.

If you think about the AIDs as kings, and **root** as a god, then there's usually no need to impersonate one of the AIDs, for root has power above each of their domains.